# Merge [ipn] and [paypal-ipn]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I've just come across these two on Stack Overflow.

[paypal-ipn](/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn) is described in its wiki as:

> Paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service
>   that sends a notification when a transaction is affected...

and [ipn](/questions/tagged/ipn) as:

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service that
>   sends a notification when a transaction is affected.

These tags should probably be merged and synonymised under [paypal-ipn](/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn).

Comment: How different is [tag:paypal-ipn] from [tag:paypal]? Do we really need a separate [tag:paypal-ipn] tag? (Just curious.)

Comment: That's a whole other question @animuson... I have no idea but I'm not going to go down the "do we need the django-* tags" route. There are over 700 questions between the two tags so I think it's fair enough to keep them. Unless, of course, someone with some knowledge of the subject (I have none just noticed dodgy tags) wants to say otherwise.

Comment: @animuson, there are other ways to interact with Paypal than their IPN mechanism, including a few different shopping cart APIs.  I'd actually argue that [tag:paypal] isn't specific enough to ever be a reasonable tag on a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right about using [paypal-ipn](/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn).  You never know when you'll end up needing a three-letter acronym for something else; better not to use it now.  Also, it's good to have the most common thing on the front of tag; for example, to be able to set favorites to `paypal*`.

Comment: Wait, youcandowhatnow?? \*goes try it\* Wow, how come I've never heard of that feature before? You deserve a +1 just for that alone!

Comment: Thanks, it's a pretty convenient feature.